# Replicating Heroku environment in Docker (or other container)

Tags: php, heroku, nginx, docker

I would like to have a local development environment that is a clone of my Heroku environment, with same dependencies, etc.

I can develop locally on my OSX machine, but I use brew for package management, and it is a chore to keep all the versions the same as my heroku setup.

My issue is I don't like deploying to my Heroku development environment every time I make a change. It really slows down my development time, waiting for the slug to compile and deploy.

Is there a way to use Docker to mimic exactly whats in my Heroku stack? (PHP, Nginx, MongoDB ... ) Anybody done this or have a link to a tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku). It uses Heroku buildpacks by default and you can add things like MongoDB instances with its plugin system (here's a [dokku mongo plugin](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mongo)).